# Syncing PouchDB and Couchbase Sync Gateway - CORS Error

Tags: couchdb, couchbase, pouchdb, couchbase-sync-gateway

I need help syncing PouchDB with Couchbase Sync Gateway.

I keep getting the following error that points to a CORS problem, but I've configured Couchbase Sync Gateway (CSG) for CORS according to their documentation.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4985/test-database/.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'header is present on the requested
resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not 
allowed access.
```

I've tried the following config file per the CSG docs:

http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/sync-gateway/configuring-sync-gateway/config-properties/index.html

```
{
  "log": ["HTTP+"],
  "CORS": {
    "origin":["http://localhost:3000"],
    "loginOrigin":["http://localhost:3000"],
    "headers":["Content-Type"],
    "maxAge": 1728000
  },
  "databases": {
    "test-database": {
      "server": "walrus:",
      "users": { "GUEST": {"disabled": false, "admin_channels": ["*"] } }
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried other config files as well from the Couchbase blog, but none of them work!  Any help with this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the only difference is port number 8k vs 3k... Can you use curl/postman to call http://localhost:3000 - to see if cors header is in result? If so - problem is with PouchDB. Other case is that your configuration was somehow ignored. I know that restarting/redoing is silly advise, or perhaps you did that. But just in case - can you confirm that? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to hit the Sync Gateway admin port, which doesn't support CORS, as far as I know.  Have you tried targeting the public port (4984)?

Comment: That was the problem.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Mine was I edited the wrong sync_gateway.json (my backup copy;)

Answer (score -1):

it's because you need to enable CORS on CouchDB. Otherwise, your scripts can only access the server database if they're served from the same origin — the protocol (ex: http://, https://), domain, and port number must match.

You can enable CORS in CouchDB using curl or the Futon web interface, but we've saved you some time by making a Node script called add-cors-to-couchdb. Just run:

```
npm install -g add-cors-to-couchdb
add-cors-to-couchdb
```

for more info, refer the link
https://pouchdb.com/errors.html#no_access_control_allow_origin_header